How to implement in a Linux terminal program the same functionality that Ctrl-T and SIGINFO provide on BSDs?
In my Linux terminal program I need users to be able to query its status using the keyboard shortcut.
Ctrl-T and SIGINFO would work great, except that they are only available on BSDs and MacOS.
Various recommendations from the Internet say that SIGUSR1 can be used for the purpose of querying the program status. But AFAIK SIGUSR1 can't be easily hooked up to the terminal shortcut like Ctrl-T.
The 'stty -a' command shows regular terminal shortcuts, for example ^Q, ^S, ^Z. But ^T isn't there on Linux.
I know that it is possible to re-define one these shortcuts, for example "quit = ^" that sends SIGQUIT, but then SIGQUIT wouldn't work as usual.
How to emulate the Ctrl-T/SIGINFO behavior on Linux without disabling any other keyboard shortcuts?

This shortcut is implemented by the terminal driver in the operating system. There's no way to add new code to the terminal driver.

Can you update your Linux terminal program to listen to keyboard events ?

Does this mean that this functionality (reporting program's status triggered by a keyboard shortcut) isn't possible on Linux without disabling other shortcuts?
